# How to calculate the sum of an attribute after an inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, aggregate-functions, management-studio-express

I'm looking to get the sum of the 'Price_amount' attribute result set.
The answer is 100+150=250 but how do I get this to display as a result set? This is my query so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM tBoard
INNER JOIN tPrice
ON tBoard.PriceBand_ID = tPrice.PriceBand_ID
WHERE Board_start_date BETWEEN '20150101' AND '20150131'
```

Result Set:

```
Board_ID|Board_start_date|Board_end_date|PriceBand_ID|Price_amount
001     |01-01-2015      |16-01-2015    |1           |100
002     |01-01-2015      |28-01-2015    |15          |150
```

I am using SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2012 Express

Comment: Maybe SUM(Price_amount)??? It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: sum might not work since you'd have to group and nothing is distinct.. you can try `SUM(Price_amount) OVER ()`.. but then again you might just want a single column and single row back so..

Comment: Simple: `SELECT Board_ID, SUM(Price_amount) AS SumOfPriceAmount  FROM tBoard INNER JOIN tPrice ON tBoard.PriceBand_ID = tPrice.PriceBand_ID WHERE Board_start_date BETWEEN '20150101' AND '20150131' GROUP BY Board_ID` Pretty basic SQL. You can set this up graphically in SSMS2012 as well. I would search for some tutorials on SQL syntax and the SSMS program itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see detalis you can use window aggregate functions.

One of the benefits of using window functions is that unlike grouped queries, windowed queries do not hide the detali. They return a row for every underlying query's row.

Using OVER clause you define a window of rows for the function.

You can try this:

```
 SELECT *, sum(Price_amount) over(order by Board_ID rows between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and current row) AS [SUM]
 FROM tBoard
 INNER JOIN tPrice
 ON tBoard.PriceBand_ID = tPrice.PriceBand_ID
 WHERE Board_start_date BETWEEN '20150101' AND '20150131'
```

or you can do with basic group by clause (no details)

```
 SELECT Board_ID,Board_start_date,Board_end_date,PriceBand_ID,sum(Price_amount) AS [SUM]
 FROM tBoard
 INNER JOIN tPrice
 ON tBoard.PriceBand_ID = tPrice.PriceBand_ID
 WHERE Board_start_date BETWEEN '20150101' AND '20150131'
 GROUP BY Board_ID,Board_start_date,Board_end_date,PriceBand_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use window functions:

```
SELECT *, SUM(price_amount) OVER () as total_price_amount
FROM tBoard b INNER JOIN
     tPrice p
     ON b.PriceBand_ID = p.PriceBand_ID
WHERE Board_start_date BETWEEN '20150101' AND '20150131';
```